# Retrieving maximum value from a range in unsorted array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have an *unsorted array*. I have numerous queries in which I give a range (expressed as two array indexes) and then the maximum value from that range (that is, from the specified slice of the array) has to be returned. 
For example:

```
array[]={23,17,9,45,78,2,4,6,90,1};
query(both inclusive): 2 6
answer: 78
```

Which algorithm or data structure do I construct to quickly retrieve maximum value from any range. (There are a lot of queries)

**EDIT:**
I am using C++

Comment: Use the built-in `max()` function of the programming language you are using. It will be the fastest.

Comment: @sudeepdino008 which language are you using.

Comment: I'd try transforming the list to a list of `(index, value)` tuples, sort that by `value` in descending order, then on a query iterate over this list and return the first value where the index is in the given range. This will get slower the smaller the ranges are related to the whole list though. For small ranges it might at some point get faster to just look up the maximum linearly.

Comment: **[cross-posted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is strictly frowned upon...'")** at Programmers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/197016/retrieving-maximum-value-from-a-range-in-unsorted-array

Comment: lol. This one of the programming question on codechef. http://ww2.codechef.com/MAY13/problems/MSTICK That requires the use of this kind of data structure

Comment: @asidsid88 I don't think inquiring about a data structure which could tackle the problem I am currently facing will account as 'cheating'. All I got from this thread was that RMQ is a suitable data structure for my purpose, I still have to study it, code it. I have asked this question in a far more broad sense and your allegations of cheating are unwelcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that some preprocessing is allowed. It is Range Minimum Query problem (maximum here).
[Good review of this problem at TopCoder](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor).
Suitable data structures: Segment tree and [Sqrt-decomposition](http://pastebin.com/Gs6wZX3V):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

#define N int(3e4)

using namespace std;

int act[N], len, sz, res[N];

int answer(int l, int r) {
        int ret = -1, i;
        for (i = l; i % sz && i <= r; i++)
                ret = max(ret, act[i]);
        for (; i + sz <= r + 1; i += sz)
                ret = max(ret, res[i / sz]);
        for (; i <= r; i++)
                ret = max(ret, act[i]);
        return ret;                                            
}

int main() {
        int i, m;
        cin >> m;
        for (i = 0; ; i++) {
                cin >> act[i];
                if (act[i] == -1)
                        break;
        }
        len = i;

        for (sz = 1; sz * sz < len; sz++);

        for (int j = i + 1; j < sz * sz; j++)
                act[j] = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < sz * sz; i++)
                res[i / sz] = max(res[i / sz], act[i]);

        for (int i = 0; i + m <= len; i++)
                cout << answer(i, i + m - 1) << endl;          

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mergesort n get the last index value of range as will me max.

array[]={23,17,9,45,78,2,4,6,90,1};
query(both inclusive): 2 6

mergesort return 6th index var (index = 1 .. n)

answer: 78

Comment: Is he going to do a new mergesort for each query? sorting might be worst idea here

Answer (score 0):

Let say this is your array `array[]={23,17,9,45,78,2,4,6,90,1};`

If your array is not that big, I would offer you preprocess the array and get another array like that:

```
{0,0} = 23; //between arr[0] and arr[0]
{0,1} = 23;
{0,2} = 23;
{0,3} = 45;

{9,9} = 1;
```

So your new array is going to be `newArr = {23,23,23,45,....., 1}`

You can find search in O(1), for example, max between 4-5 is `newArr[4*array.length+5)-1];`
In total, for n queries you will have O(n).

The space is if you have **10000(10^4) integer**, then your **newArr = 10^8 * 4B = 400MB**, so if you have more than **10000 int**, then this wouldnt work

**EDIT:** I thought of something but it is same as [algorithm in Topcoder](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor) that **MBo** mentions.

Comment: I am having about (10^5) length array.